# Why after adding $interval other call to funtions stop working?

Tags: angularjs, intervals

I'm working on an app developed by other people, I don't have any documentation or any way to contact them, and I have this problem:

It's an angular application that need to be refreshed every minute, In other sections of the app, they are using $interval, but in this page if I try to use it, the calls to my WebAPI stop working and I recive this error:

```
WebApiFactory.getNoStatusOrders is not a function
```

I need your help to know why is this happening, here is my code:

```
angular.module('AssemblyLive').controller('overviewCarsWithoutStatus', [
'$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'WebApiFactory', "$interval", 'StatusPointMonitorFactory',
function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $interval, WebApiFactory, StatusPointMonitorFactory) {
    ...
    var areas = {
        bodyShop1:"B000,B001,B020,B031,B200,B211,B220,B231,B300,B311,B320,B331,B370,B371,B375,B376,B380,B381,B383,B386,B390,B400,B401,B410,B420,B421,B425,B426,B430",
        bodyShop2: "B431,B435,B436,B440,B451,B500,B521,B540,B551,B553,B600,B750,B760,B770,B781,B783,B790,B791,B800,B811,B813,B900",
        paintShop1: "D000,D011,D012,D051,D100,D130,D131,D132,D151,D152,D230,D251,D252,D300,D351,D352,D360,D381,D390,D400,D451,D452,D470",
        paintShop2: "D471,D472,D481,D482,D500,D501,D531,D532,D540,D561,D562,D600,D620,D650,D670,D691,D692,D700,D731,D741,D750,D800,D812,D821,D822,D841,D842",
        assembly: "F000,F100,F150,F200,F250,F300,F350,F400,F450,F500,F550,F600,F650,F700,F750,F800,F850,F900"
    };
    ...
    //Start the creation of the overview.
    function initializeOverview() {
        $scope.counters = [];
        //Iterates over the configuration.

        //Get all the status to call the query.
        var status = $scope.headers.map(function(a) {return a.status.toString();});
        //Call to create the knrs b y area.
        getKNRWithoutStatus(status.toString());


        for(var status in areas){
            getCarsWithNoStatus(areas[status]);
        }

        getNoStatusCounters("B000,C000,D000,E000,E500,F000,F100,F950,G000,G900");

    }
    // Funtion to set the counters in the table headers
    function getNoStatusCounters(status) {
         WebApiFactory.getNoStatusOrdersCounter(status).then(function (resultData) {
            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(resultData.NoStatusOrders).forEach(function(name) {
    ...
    function getCarsWithNoStatus(status) {
        // Fetch all the counters from the WebAPI
        WebApiFactory.getNoStatusOrdersCounter(status).then(function (resultData) {
            ...

    function getKNRWithoutStatus(status) {
        var orders = [];
        //Query the status monitor.
        WebApiFactory.getNoStatusOrders(status).then(function(statusMonData) {
            ...

    /** To refresh data when the clock in the footer refresh. */
    $rootScope.$on('carsWithoutStatusOverview', function(){
        initializeOverview();
        $interval(initializeOverview, Config.dataRefreshInterval * 1000)
    });
```

Note: My page works perfectly without adding $interval

Comment: Where the `areas` variable was defined?

Comment: It's defined as a global variable at the beginning of the code (question edited)

Comment: I just added more of my code, I can't paste all because is too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review your dependency injection. You put `WebApiFactory` and `$interval` in different positions in the $inject list and in the parameters. (So the `$interval` variable points to your `WebApiFactory` service and vice versa.)

Comment: For real? does that matter?, I had so,me ideas of angular, but never actually used it until now, so I didn't believe that it was important the position.

Comment: Absolutely. The string array tells angular which registered services to inject in which parameter position. The parameter name itself is just the arbitrary local variable name.

Comment: I should note: If the $inject list is omitted, Angular will TRY to provide services matching parameter names. But that's not reliable if you minify the code. The parameter names will get replaced with short one or two letter tokens and Angular will no longer be able to match them. That's why the array syntax is there. The strings are minification-safe.